# Spark 2.1.x Dataset API - Understanding groupByKey & reduceGroups behavior

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I was playing around with the Dataset API to reduce some elements and I noticed a "strange" but maybe normal behavior.

When applying a `reduceGroups` on my `KeyValueGroupedDataset`, and if I print the data inside it, a same record is printed twice. Using an `accumulator` shows the same behavior.

If I use the RDD API for the exact same purpose, my prints appear only once per key (when I have exactly two records for a same grouping key, of course)

I was expecting the `reduceGroups` in Dataset API to behave the same as a `combineByKey` / `reduceByKey` in RDD API. Have you ever faced this ?

Here are two reproducible examples for both `Dataset` and `RDD` approaches :

**Dataset API** (Spark 2.1.x) :

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("A","1","df1"),
  ("B","2","df1"),
  ("C","3","df1")
).toDF("pk1", "pk2", "df")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("df", lit("df2"))

val df = (df1 union df2).groupByKey(_.toSeq.take(2).mkString(","))
  .reduceGroups { (r1, r2) =>
    println(r1, r2)
    r1
  }
.toDF("key","value").show(false)

+---+---------+
|key|value    |
+---+---------+
|B,2|[B,2,df1]|
|C,3|[C,3,df1]|
|A,1|[A,1,df1]|
+---+---------+
```

Output (println) with duplicated lines :

```
([B,2,df1],[B,2,df2])
([B,2,df1],[B,2,df2])
([C,3,df1],[C,3,df2])
([A,1,df1],[A,1,df2])
([C,3,df1],[C,3,df2])
([A,1,df1],[A,1,df2])
```

**Same with RDD API** :

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("A","1","df1"),
  ("B","2","df1"),
  ("C","3","df1")
).toDF("pk1", "pk2", "df")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("df", lit("df2"))

(df1.rdd union df2.rdd).keyBy(_.toSeq.take(2).mkString(","))
  .reduceByKey{ (r1, r2) =>
    println(r1, r2)
    r1
  }
  .mapValues(_.toSeq.map(_.toString)).toDF("key","value").show(false)

+---+-----------+
|key|value      |
+---+-----------+
|C,3|[C, 3, df1]|
|A,1|[A, 1, df1]|
|B,2|[B, 2, df1]|
+---+-----------+
```

Output (println) with unique lines :

```
([C,3,df1],[C,3,df2])
([B,2,df1],[B,2,df2])
([A,1,df1],[A,1,df2])
```

**Update** : As Blackbishop pointed out, this seems to be a bug in Spark versions < 2.2

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with the provided example. The output of println isn't duplicated.

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop it must be version specific. I'll try with a different version (my client currently uses spark version 2.1, pretty old now). Nevertheless if you find a github PR / release note about this I'd be glad to know and could definately be an answer to my question.